# Flux query - remove consecutive duplicate values from final result

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I want to query all the data, but to skip from result the rows which have the previous row with same value.

Lets say I have these rows:

```
{ time: 0, value: 3}
{ time: 1, value: 4}
{ time: 2, value: 5}
{ time: 3, value: 5}
{ time: 4, value: 3}
{ time: 5, value: 3}
{ time: 6, value: 2}
{ time: 7, value: 1}
{ time: 8, value: 2}
```

I want to return only:

`{ time: 0, value: 3}
{ time: 1, value: 4}
{ time: 2, value: 5}
{ time: 3, value: 5} <-- same value like previous, not in result
{ time: 4, value: 3}
{ time: 5, value: 3} <-- same value like previous, not in result
{ time: 6, value: 2}
{ time: 7, value: 1}
{ time: 8, value: 2}`